Understanding memory allocation and resizing of Vectors in C++
I'm relatively new to programming in C++ and I'm trying to understand how vectors work. I've read some documentation and tutorials, but I'm still a bit confused about the basics.
Specifically, I'd like to know:
How does memory allocation and resizing work with vectors?

You can check any open source's implementation of std::vector How is vector implemented

I think the best way to understand how it works, is by trying to implement it yourself. Try something simple, without templates, and only the most basic interface to add, remove, and get elements.

It allocates memory for a certain amount of items, and keeps a pointer to that memory. When adding a new item doesn't fit anymore, it allocates new memory, moves the existing items to the new memory and deletes the old memory. And then when the vector is destructed is will delete the currently allocated memory.

What is unclear in the tutorials you have read so far? Do they not explain something you want to know? Without understanding what you don't understand, best we can do is to link to you to another tutorial.
